# How to get RGB values from the Paint object

Tags: java, android

I have the following:

```
mPaintRefernce.getColor()
```

How would I retrieve the RGB values in the range of 0-255, so Red = 200, Blue = 120 etc?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's possible, use the `android.graphics.Color` class provided by android framework

1. `Color.red(int color);` to get the red integer value from color
2. `Color.green(int color);` to get the green integer value from color
3. `Color.blue(int color);` to get the blue integer value from color

For example, to get the red color.

```
int red = Color.red(mPaintRefernce.getColor());
```

Comment: I mean like internally, how does Color.red work out the value?

Comment: It uses a bit operator. For red method, `(color >> 16) & 0xFF`

Comment: It returns 0 for me, I'm doing: 
mOriginalBlue = (double) Color.blue(mPaintRefernce.getColor());

Comment: What's the original color?

Comment: It's a paint object that has random RGB values. I've loaded it a few times (which has green) loaded but it still returns 0.

Comment: How is that random RGB values formed? `Random` class?

Comment: I've performed a test. My sample color was `#333333` and it didn't returned zero

Comment: The colour is visible on the screen, yet the result always returns 0?
Example (Functions is just system out) Functions.out("Color Blue: " + Color.blue(mPaintRefernce.getColor()));

Comment: You have to pass the color in paint by doing `paint.setColor(int color)`

Comment: You shouldn't pass the color in Paint constructor. It is for paint flags